# Dungeon Siege 2 vs Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dungeon-siege-2

I have a Dell Dimension 8400 running Windows XP & Dungeon Siege 2 Chinese version runs fine. The item information pop-up displays the numeric values, etc.

I also have another modern laptop with Windows 7 & Dungeon Siege 2 Chinese version runs fine, however the item information pop-up displays blank values for damage etc.

Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Try compatibility mode for XP SP2 ?